# Zero downtime deploy with node.js and mongodb?

Tags: linux, node.js, mongodb, deployment

I'm looking after building a global app from the ground up that can be updated and scaled transparently to the user.

The architecture so far is very easy, each part of the application has it own process and talk to other trough sockets.

This way i can spawn as many instances i want for each part of the application and distribute them across the globe accordingly to my needs.

In the front of the system i'll have a load balancer, which will them route the users to their closest instance, and when new code is spawned my instances will spawn new processes with the new  code and route new requests to it and gracefully shutdown.

Thank you very much for any advice.

Edit:

**The question is**: What is the best ( and simplest ) solution for achieving zero downtime when deploying node to multiple instances ?

About the app:

https://github.com/Raynos/boot for "socket" connections,
http for http requests,
mongo for database

Solutions i'm trying at the moment:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/thalassa ( which managed haproxy configuration files and app instances ), if you don't know it, watch this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6QkNt4hZWQ and be aware crowsnest is being replaced by https://github.com/PearsonEducation/thalassa-consul

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Sorry if wasn't clear. I made it very clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Deployment with zero downtime is only possible if the data you share between old and new nodes are compatible.

So in case you change the structure, you have to build a intermediate release, that can handle the old and new data structure without utilizing the new structure until you have replaced all nodes with that intermediate version. Then roll out the new version.

Taking nodes in and out of production can be done with your loadbalancer (and a grace time until all sessions expired on the nodes) (don't know enough about your application).

Comment: Simple node application: Uses https://github.com/Raynos/boot for "socket" connections, simple http server for http requests and mongo for database.

Comment: In this case i share the data, and its compatible. its a remote mongo db.

Comment: As load balancer i'm using haproxy being managed by thalassa-aqueduct but was looking into other options. ideally an option with GUI since i'll be rolling many instances and versions often.